# UNITY 2019.3.3 WebGL (wasm) out of executable memory on IOS

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, ipad, webassembly, unity-webgl

I have scene in test which includes just one UI Element Button. 
Publish Settings:
wasm
compression format: brotli

Strip engine:enable

First time load perfectly on ipad with os 13.3 but on refresh it throws the error "**Out of executable memory**"